# Diffcoeff package - Higher order derivatives

Tags: koma-script, diffcoeff

I would like to use [diffcoeff](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/diffcoeff) package version 5.1 for writing sort of the derivates, like in example below. Although the example is simple, it can't be compiled. The problem is with the expression `\diff[n+1]yx` and `\diffp[n+1]yx`.

The expressions are copied from page 12 and 13 of the package manual. What is wrong here? I'm worried that something is wrong with the library itself or Koma-script.

It works if I replace `scrbook` with `article` documentclass.

MNWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\listfiles
\usepackage{diffcoeff}   

\begin{document}
  \[\diff[2]yx\]
  x\[\diff[n+1]yx.\]

  \[ \diffp[2]yx\] 
  \[\diffp[n+1]yx. \]
\end{document}
```

Log:

```
(C:\...MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty))) (grain0089_c.aux)
! Use of \__seq_put_left_aux:w doesn't match its definition.
\l_tmpa_seq ->d
               iffcoeff.sty
l.13   \[\diffp[n+1]yx.
                        \]
?
! Emergency stop.
\l_tmpa_seq ->d
               iffcoeff.sty
l.13   \[\diffp[n+1]yx.
```

Listfiles:

```
 scrbook.cls    2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas    
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b    
asics and keyval usage)
scrlfile.sty    2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty    2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)      
 scrlogo.sty    2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script package (logo)
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
tocbasic.sty    2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)      
typearea.sty    2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script package (type area)
diffcoeff.sty    2023/01/16 v5.1 Write differential coefficients easily and con    
sistently.
xtemplate.sty    2023-01-16 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
   expl3.sty    2023-01-16 L3 programming layer (loader)
l3backend-dvips.def    2023-01-16 L3 backend support: dvips
mleftright.sty    2019/12/03 v1.2 Math left/right delim. as open/close (HO)        
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)        
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)        
 ***********
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have overlooked an initialization statement. The routine `\__diffcoeff_evaluate:NN` on line 531 of `diffcoeff v5.1` needs the statements

```
\seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
\seq_clear:N \l_tmpb_seq
```

immediately after the opening `{`. (Apparently `scrbook` also uses `\l_tmpa_seq`. Your example compiles with e.g. `article` class.) I will upload v5.2 of `diffcoeff` to CTAN shortly with this correction (and better handling of an empty differentiation variable argument).

Comment: Andrew is an exemplary developer and very responsive to users.